# Jquery tooltips, get data from other attribute

Tags: jquery, tooltip, jquery-tooltip

Due to my page have other jquery plugin that use title attribute, so is that possible for my jquery tooltips to get data from other attribute other than "title"?
http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html#configuration

```
<span class="something" title="This is title" otherattr="This is the tooltips"></span>
```

Comment: What tooltip are you using?qtip?qtip2?Provide as much info as possible when you ask a question.

Comment: Have you tried: $(".something[otherattr]").tooltip();

Comment: @Nicola: He provided the link to the tooltip lib he is using.

Comment: $(".something[otherattr]").tooltip(); cant really work, tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand jTools Tooltip documentation correctly, if you setup the tooltip by a selector other then $("[title]") it will use the element immediately following the trigger as the tooltip content.

So you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //place a span  with class tooltip after each element with otherattr attribute placing the otherattr text inside it
   $("[otherattr]").each(function(){
       $(this).after('<span class="tooltip">' + $(this).attr("otherattr") + '</span>');
   });

   //when we initate the tooltip this way it will use the .tooltip span after each element. 
   $("[otherAttr]").tooltip(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a function as the content for the tooltip and programmatically get the content from the attribute. In this case, you wanted the attribute 'otherattr', so you can try the following:

```
$(".something").tooltip({
    "content": function(){ 
        return $(this).attr("otherattr"); 
    }
});
```

I had to dig through some source code to figure this one out, by default the tooltip's 'content' can be found by doing

```
$(".something").tooltip("option", "content")
```

and see that it returns:

```
function (){var e=t(this).attr("title")||"";return t("<a>").text(e).html()}
```

So just write your own instead of using the default function. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".something").tooltip({
    items: '[otherattr]',
    content: function(){ 
        return $(this).attr("otherattr"); 
    }
});
```